# How does the postfix-operator actually work?

Tags: java, postfix-operator

I'm having a program that prints the value of an integer number `x` after a post-increment operation. I want to know what actually happened during that operation?

The post-increment operator first assign the value then increment it but this didn't happen in the **first example**, I don't know if this because it is assigned to the same variable `x` so the memory will not be affected twice on the same variable in one operation!

```
int x = 1; //x = 1
x = x++; //x = 1 
System.out.println(x); //x = 1
```

```
int x = 1; //x = 1
int y = 1; //y = 1
y = x++; //y = 1, x = 2
System.out.println(x); //x = 2
```

I expect the output of `x` to be `2`, but the actual output is `1`

Comment: The assignment to `x` takes place after the postincrement, but it uses the preincrement value.

Comment: It also makes no sense to write it like that in any case whatsoever, as entire assignment expression will evaluate to x too. In worst case, in languages like C++, it will be undefined behaviour, which is even worse than unreadable "NOP".

Comment: I didn't know that thanks a lot @user207421